# Why can I only access PI via IPV6 and not the IP address I set in dhcpcd.conf?

Tags: pi-3, ssh, ethernet

I am trying to configure a static ip address to connect to the PI from my PC with an Ethernet cable. I tried following the instructions to configure a static IP address on raspberry pi 3

appended to end of the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.6/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1


interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.7/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Rebooted (sudo reboot, and tried with hard power cycle)

Tried ssh to either ethernet ip address or wife ip address, neither work 
Then I try

```
ping raspberry.pi
```

I get back what looks like an ipv6 address, and am able to access through this address.

Why can't I access the Raspberry PI via its static ip address?

Comment: Check your static IP address. Notice that the router is on 192.168.0.x network and your IP is on 192.168.1.x

Comment: @ChefFlambe good catch, still no good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to configure my PC IPv4 on that ethernet to use static ip address too, in the same range

[image]

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.